# Debug Qt/C++ with stepping through core libraries source code

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm trying to debug a crash that happens when I call `QList` method `size()`. I would like to step through the source of that method to try to get a better understanding of the error, however, the only thing i have are the binaries and the header files.

Is there a way to have the source source of the core libs available through the debug process?

Comment: If you really want to, you can download the source files, but you're likely to find that the bug is going to be in your code, not Qt: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Get_The_Source

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: How would you set up Qt to actually show those sources when debugging?

Comment: @LennartRolland, build Qt, from source, in debug.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: I  was hoping you would not say that :P